# Typescript - Is it possible to have interface defining a constructor with generics?

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm basically trying to do something like this:

```
interface gen1<T> {
    constructor(param: T);
}
interface gen2<T> {
    constructor(param: gen1<any>);
}
class genImpl implements gen2<any> {
    constructor(param: gen1<any>) {

    }
}
```

but getting error:

```
Class 'genImpl' incorrectly implements interface 'gen2<any>'.
  Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(param: gen1<any>) => any'.
      Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(param: gen1<any>): any'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constructor signatures in interfaces are not implementable in classes. This is by design. From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types):

> When working with classes and interfaces, it helps to keep in mind
>   that a class has two types: the type of the static side and the type
>   of the instance side. You may notice that if you create an interface
>   with a construct signature and try to create a class that implements
>   this interface you get an error:
>
> ```
> interface ClockConstructor {
>     new (hour: number, minute: number);
> }
>
> class Clock implements ClockConstructor {
>     currentTime: Date;
>     constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
> }
> ```
>
> This is because when a class implements an interface, only the
>   instance side of the class is checked. Since the constructor sits in
>   the static side, it is not included in this check.
>
> Instead, you would need to work with the static side of the class
>   directly. In this example, we define two interfaces, ClockConstructor
>   for the constructor and ClockInterface for the instance methods. Then
>   for convenience we define a constructor function createClock that
>   creates instances of the type that is passed to it.
>
> ```
> interface ClockConstructor {
>     new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
> }
> interface ClockInterface {
>     tick();
> }
>
> function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
>     return new ctor(hour, minute);
> }
>
> class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
>     constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
>     tick() {
>         console.log("beep beep");
>     }
> }
> class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
>     constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
>     tick() {
>         console.log("tick tock");
>     }
> }
>
> let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17); let analog =
> createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
> ```
>
> Because createClock’s first parameter
>   is of type ClockConstructor, in createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32), it
>   checks that AnalogClock has the correct constructor signature.

Related discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8917

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I like to use abstract classes, e.g:

```js
interface ClockInterface {
    tick();
}

abstract class ClockAdapter {
    constructor(readonly hour: number, readonly minute: number) {
    }
}

class DigitalClock extends ClockAdapter implements ClockInterface {
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}

class AnalogClock extends ClockAdapter implements ClockInterface {
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = new DigitalClock(12, 17);
let analog = new AnalogClock(7, 32);
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is it possible to have generics in constructor?

Yes

> but getting error

The reason is `gen<T>` is not the same as `T`

## Fix

```
interface gen<T> {
    constructor(param: T);
}

class genImpl implements gen<any> {
    constructor(param: any) {

    }
}
```

i.e. use `any` where ever `T` was used. (you made the mistake of putting `T` to both `gen<any>` and `any`)

Comment: Did you mean to write `declare class` or a combination of `interface`, `new()`, and `const`? This will not work because constructors are essentially static.

Comment: @basarat you are my typescript hero, but this is just plain wrong. your code sample exactly raises the error in question.